# Subtraction from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

for a dictionary,

```
d = {'a': 1}
```

when we perform a subtraction,

```
d - ['a']
```

gives,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'list'
```

and,

```
d.values() - ['a']
```

gives,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict_values' and 'list'
```

whereas,

```
d.keys() - ['a']
```

gives,

```
set()
```

this is different from let us say how contains works,

```
print('a' in d, 'a' in d.keys(), 'a' in d.values())
```

gives,

```
True True False
```

what could be the reason for this inconsistency,
should it not be that,

```
d - ['a']
```

gives,

```
set()
```

and,

```
d.values() - ['a']
```

gives,

```
{1}
```

Comment: Why should subtracting a list from a dict turn it into a set?, what if you're subtracting `['a', 'invalid']` what would you expect then?

Comment: `d` does not contain `a` as a value, `a` is a key which has a value of `1`.

Comment: In what way do the behavior of `__sub__` and `__contains__` imply an inconsistency? While one *could* define a relationship between the two, it would first require that both are defined. `__sub__` simply isn't defined for dicts or lists, while it is defined for sets.

Comment: The `keys` method returns a view object to the keys of the dict that specifically implements the set interface. The `values` method and the `dict` class itself do not.

Comment: It's not opinion based. There are various reasons why the op's suggestion is impossible and I've listed them. You can add more if you wish, but it doesn't reflect any opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Substraction from a dictionary is ambiguous, that's why it's not implemented. What do you do with the values in that case?

The values themselves are more like a list, so that's ambiguous as well. What happens when you remove a list from a list?

Keys however behave like a set, with only a single occurrence of each key (no repeated elements). Substraction in case of a set is implemented as the difference between the first and second operands.

Overall, checking if a container contains an object using the `in` operator does not imply anything about what to do when subtracting a list that contains the object from the container.